# Spring Data Rest Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

У меня есть entity User :

```
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "login")
private String login;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
// others fields
```

Spring Data Rest создает маппинг для этой энтити, но когда я пытаюсь по ней перейти ловлю:

```
  {"cause":{"cause":{"cause":null,"message":"Provided id of the wrong type for class com.v2gdemo.backend.entity.User. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer"},"message":"Provided id of the wrong type for class com.v2gdemo.backend.entity.User. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer"},"message":"Provided id of the wrong type for class com.v2gdemo.backend.entity.User. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.v2gdemo.backend.entity.User. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer"}
```

Если айди изменить на int тогда все работает корректно, в чем же проблема ?? С другими энтити таких проблем нету, независимо от типа Id.

Comment: репозиторий покажите, чем он типизирован в дженрике? а еще загляните в бд. какого типа тап колонка айдишника?

Comment: Проверьте сеттер для id. Проверьте весь путь где тянется id. Определенно в каком-то месте будет преобразование long->int

Comment: В данном случае в базе данных поле id не является длинным.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте сеттер.
У вас

```
private Long id;
```

А ругается на Integer. Вероятно там стоит setId(Integer id)

Comment: Спасибо коментаторам за помощь, проблема в том, что в репозитории был Integer!